# Do expired memcache items autodelete?

Tags: php, memcached

I set an item in memcache at 00:54 this morning with an expiration time of 30 minutes. When I came back to the office this morning, I called the same key from memcache and was surprised to retrieve it as it was meant to have expired. Will the item only get removed if memcache runs out of memory? Or is it more likely that there is an error in my script?

I am using PHP and the memcache object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as a memcached key hits it expiry time, retrieving it will return the same result as trying to retrieve a key that never existed.

Comment: I thought so and I think I have found the error in my code. Thank you very much.